# Qt QCompleter can't have its size set?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QCompleter` attached to a `QLineEdit` and it works fine, except the suggestion popups are the width of the line edit, while I need them to be wider. There aren't any methods in the completer that seem to allow me to change this. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Subclass `QAbstractItemView` in which you can set width and then set this customized class to `QCompleter::setPopup(QAbstractItemView * popup)`

Comment: are there cookie-cutter instructions on how to do this? There seem to be a few pure virtual methods that I have to reimplement

Comment: We can add QTreeView instead with one row and set QTableView::resizeColumnToContents(). This may help you with easy way

Answer (score 1):

It can be set in the QAbstractView * popup() item. My try:

```
// compute needed width
const QAbstractItemView * popup = _completer->popup();
int padding = popup->width() - popup->viewport()->width();
int scrollbarWidth = qApp->style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_ScrollBarExtent);
int frameWidth = popup->frameWidth();
int textWidth = popup->fontMetrics().boundingRect(QLocale().toString(string)).width();
int desiredWidth = textWidth + 4 * padding + 2 * frameWidth + scrollbarWidth;

// set it
_completer->popup()->setMinimumWidth(desiredWidth);
```

Result (Tested on Windows 7, magnify 2x):
[image]